# Problems compiling with libraries

Tags: makefile, cgal

I am trying to compile some C++ code which uses the CGAL library on OS X Lion. I downloaded and installed on some directory the CGAL library. Then, when I try to compile the code, using "make";

```
triangulation.h:18:64: error: CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h: No such file or directory
```

which means it does not find the CGAL lib. I look at the Makefile, and I see that it compiles using the flag

```
-lCGAL
```

Wondering how to solve this, I guess I could pass the information about the placement of my compiled library to this variable, but I do not how. I tried with export and so on but it does not recognize it, any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message doesn't mean the *library* isn't found; it means a *header file* isn't found. The  `-lCGAL` switch does indeed refer to the library. You're going to need a `-IXXXXX` switch added on to `CFLAGS`, where *`XXXXX`* is the path to the directory containing the `CGAL` directory which in turn contains `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h` .

Comment: the problem I see is that the code, internally uses in a lot of places the "value" of CGAL like #include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K; so I do not know how to overcome this

Comment: Follow my instructions carefully, and that will do it. The `-I` flag adds a directory in which to search for include files. You want the compiler to search in a directory that *contains* the `CGAL` directory which contains the header files.

Comment: I took into account your advices, but it does not work yet. I do not know whether an error source could be the fact that in the CGAL lib directory, there is nothing called strictly CGAL, but variants of that name

Comment: Did you actually *install* CGAL, or just unpack it somewhere? Is nothing installed into, e.g., `/usr/include/CGAL`, or `/opt/local/include/CGAL`, or some other system directory?

Comment: I compiled it; make; make install and used the prefix in order to install it in a defaul directory for my user

Comment: A bounty? What other kind of answer are you looking for? The headers for this library apparently expect to be installed in a directory named CGAL, and that directory needs to be on the include path. This is not rocket science -- it's trivial, actually -- but you need to explain what part of this you don't understand.

Comment: exactly, this is not rocket science -for you-

Comment: nevertheless you will be fairly rewarded with the bounty and have a nice weekend